# add checkbox to subtab on a NetSuite form

Tags: checkbox, netsuite

This may be a simple quesiton but I need to ask to be sure I am in the correct direction.  In the Item Fulfillment form for example, there is a first column Fulfill that is a checkbox.  Above it there are buttons for Mark All and Unmark All as well.  What I would like to do is have similar functionality on one of my other subtabs.  I already have a custom child record that lives on my subtab and added a checkbox bool field to the record.  I could get that to somewhat work but what I would like to know is 
1- is that the  correct approach.
2- does it need to be a field that is selected to be saved, 
3- for their functionality this only appears in Edit mode.  is that a limitation?
4- I notice their "checkbox field" is not as wide as the one I made 
5- Is there a way that I would only get this "field" to appear in the record when it is in a sublist and not when it is in its own custom form to create a new item?  I would only have it as a checkbox in a subtab.

Or is my approach wrong and perhaps there is an easier way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You can create a check box using inline HTML field - script the check box that way. Call a client script's function to handle the click.
2 - Not really sure what you're talking about - if you mean "Store Value" in the field definition, the answer is "No".
3 - Edit mode, yes. You can't change values of a field when not in edit mode.
4 - Width of a field can be controlled on the form design.
5 - Create 2 different forms. The data entry form would not include the check box, the sublist form would.

Comment: I think this answered my questions though some of the answers my not be quite what I had hoped to hear. :).  Thanks. Do you know of any place that could point me in the direction of creating an HTML inline field?